# GridLayout auto_fit columns

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

Is there a way to tell GridLayout that I want my columns to be at least x dp wide and calculate the columnCount based on that dynamically.

For GridView there is an `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` setting that does that.

Comment: Why you cannot use `GridView`? `GridLayout` has not "principle of weights"

Comment: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout ?

Comment: @Ragnar I'm building a header view for a GridView already. I cannot place another GridView to a GridView.

Comment: @XOOLOOO This doesn't stretch my items.